# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringRest'

Tags: spring, servlets

I am trying to hit the url but I am 404 error & in console I am getting warning as **WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-mvc/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringRest'**

I am not sure about the web.xml settings. My code is like below.
Any help would be appreaciated. Thanks in Advance..

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

TestController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.wocs.services.common.ServiceException;
import com.wocs.services.order.iface.OrderServiceIface;
import com.wocs.services.order.model.hiera.OrderHiera;


@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() throws ServiceException
    {
     return "Hello............";    
    }
}
```

SpringRest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd" >


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.wocs" />
    <import resource="classpath:/beanfactory/service-bean-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC or Boot?

Comment: Spring MVC.....

Comment: Highly recommend using Spring Boot, make your life so much easier. _Make **JAR** not **WAR**_

Answer (score 0):

It might be the `@RequestMapping("/hello")` as you're NOT defining what type of method is used to receive the request.

Try this

```
@GetMapping(value="/hello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> hello() throws ServiceException
{
 return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello............", HttpStatus.OK);    
}
```

Comment: Syntax error on token ""/hello"", invalid MemberValuePairs

Comment: Sorry my bad, let me fix it

Comment: @rahulshalgar Try that

Comment: Have you got following import statements? `import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;`, `import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;`, `import org.springframework.http.MediaType;`, `import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;`

Comment: Opps, it was this `@GetMapping(value="/hello",` not having `value` maping.

Comment: I am not getting... could you please correct the code?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Controller class like this and tell me if it works

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

     @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() throws ServiceException
    {
     return "Hello............";    
    }
}
```

if this doesn't work you can try

```
@Controller
    public class TestController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public String hello() throws ServiceException
        {
         return "Hello............";    
        }
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

check that your web.xml file and SpringRest-servlet.xml file is in **webapp/WEB-INF** folder, also check that your controller java class is in **src/main/java** and not in **src/main/test** , most of the time improper directory structure causes the problem. Let me know if it still does not work.

Comment: check that your controller java file is in src/main/java folder and not in src/main/test also check if your web.xml file is same as above

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml file:-

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringRest-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```